# Ошибки proguard после перехода на Android Studio3, Gradle 3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard

После обновления начали возникать ошибки такого вида:

> Warning: library class android.animation.AnimatorInflater depends on program class android.content.Context
>   Warning: library class android.animation.AnimatorInflater depends on program class android.content.Context
>   Warning: library class android.animation.ObjectAnimator depends on program 
>   Warning: library class android.app.ActivityOptions depends on program class android.graphics.Rect
>   Warning: library class org.xml.sax.ext.DefaultHandler2 depends on program class org.xml.sax.InputSource

И такого:

> Warning: library class android.app.NotificationChannelGroup extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
>   Warning: library class android.app.NotificationManager$Policy extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
>   Warning: library class android.app.PictureInPictureParams extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
>   Warning: library class android.app.Presentation extends or implements program class android.app.Dialog
>   Warning: library class android.app.RemoteAction extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable
>   Warning: library class android.app.RemoteInput extends or implements program class android.os.Parcelable

Их много:

> Warning: there were 1074 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
>            You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
>            be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
>
> Warning: there were 132 unresolved references to program class members.
>            Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
>            You may need to recompile the code.

Чтобы собиралось в новом gradle обновил : `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'`, `compileSdkVersion 26`,     `buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'`.

Поменял `provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.+'`на `annotationProcessor 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.+'`

И добавил в `packagingOptions` `{exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'}`

Вот часть моего `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    // multidex support dependency
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    // support libraries dependencies
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'

    compile fileTree(include: '*jar', dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.2.0'

    compile 'org.opencv:opencv-android:2.4.6@aar'
    compile 'com.github.gabrielemariotti.changeloglib:library:1.4.0@aar'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.2@aar'
    compile 'org.jcodec:jcodec:0.1.10'
    annotationProcessor 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.+'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.intellij:annotations:12.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.luckycatlabs:SunriseSunsetCalculator:1.2'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    compile 'com.flurry:android:3.4.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.6'

    // crashreporting (with NDK Kit)
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'

    // youtube api integration dependencies
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev125-1.19.1'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.19.1'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.19.1'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.19.1'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-jackson2:1.19.1'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-appengine:1.19.1'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:1.19.0'

    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2@jar'
    compile('com.vk:androidsdk:1.3.3@aar') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.19.1@aar') { transitive = true }
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'

    // network interaction
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2'

    // billing
    compile 'org.solovyev.android:checkout:0.7.4@aar'

    // social networks integration dependencies
    compile(name: 'ASNECore', ext: 'aar') { exclude module: 'core' }
    compile(name: 'facebook', ext: 'aar') { exclude module: 'facebook' }
    compile(name: 'instagram', ext: 'aar') { exclude module: 'instagram' }
    compile(name: 'linkedin', ext: 'aar') { exclude module: 'linkedin' }
    compile(name: 'odnoklassniki', ext: 'aar') { exclude module: 'odnoklassniki' }
    compile(name: 'twitter', ext: 'aar') { exclude module: 'twitter' }
    compile(name: 'vk', ext: 'aar') { exclude module: 'vk' }

    compile(name: 'pathsense-android-sdk-bundle-release-2.3.0.6', ext: 'aar')

    //androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    testCompile 'org.easymock:easymock:3.1'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.5.1'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.5.1'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.5.1'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-easymock:1.5.1'
    testCompile 'com.google.mockwebserver:mockwebserver:20130706'
    testCompile ('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-plugin-registry'
        exclude module: 'maven-profile'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'nekohtml'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-shared'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: я в соседнем вопросе ответил, повторюсь, внимательно читайте гайд по миграции от гугл https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html там всё всё написано

Comment: @SviatVolkov Делал и по нему, та же проблема. В дебаге сейчас всё собирается.

Comment: обновите тогда в вопросе код, я не вижу чтобы вы обновили зависимости